# how get and pass values in servlet in java?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I have Java code like this,
package my.ebill.pro.db;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import newt.com.properties.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;


@WebServlet("/BG_Form")
public class BG_Form extends MyDbConn {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2319984741700546377L;
    static Statement st,st1;

    public BG_Form() throws Exception {
        super();
        st=con.createStatement();
        st1=con.createStatement();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


    String poNumberBas=request.getParameter("poNo");
    String fromPoBas=request.getParameter("toAddress");
    String toPoBas=request.getParameter("toWhomname");
    String[] productsBas = request.getParameterValues("product");
    String[] pricesBas= request.getParameterValues("price");
    String[] qtysBas= request.getParameterValues("qty");
    String[] linetotalsBas = request.getParameterValues("linetotal");
         System.out.println("Product"+productsBas);
    /*out.println( poNumber + fromPo+toPo+products+prices+qtys+linetotals+"Adress");*/
    PoGet poget=new PoGet();
    poget.setFromPo(fromPoBas);
    poget.setToPo(toPoBas);
    poget.setProducts(productsBas);
    poget.setPrices(pricesBas);
    poget.setPoNumber(poNumberBas);
    poget.setQtys(qtysBas);
    poget.setLinetotals(linetotalsBas);

    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

> here getter and setter;

```
public class PoGet {

    private String poNumber;
    private String fromPo;
    private String toPo;
    private String[] products;
    private String[] prices;
    private String[] qtys;
    private String[] linetotals;
}
```

and jsp code is

```
<html>
<head>
<%@include file="includes/headscript.jsp" %> 
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="validationform" name="validationform" method="get" action="BG_Form">
<input type="text" style="border-right-width: 2px; margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 33px; margin-top: -15px;" id="F_Date" class="dateRagePicker leftPick1 hasDatepicker" maxlength="20" size="20">
<table class="order-list" style="margin-left: 228px;">
    <thead>
        <tr><td>Product</td><td>Price</td><td>Qty</td><td>Total</td></tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="product"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="price">
            </td><td><input type="text" name="qty"></td>
            <td><input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="linetotal"></td>
            <td><a class="deleteRow"> x </a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align: center;" colspan="5">
                <input type="button" value="Add Product" name="addrow" id="addrow">

            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                Grand Total: Rs<span id="grandtotal"></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        In Words <span id="inworDs" ></span>

        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>
                <input type="submit"/>

        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

</form>



<script>
    $("#addrow").click(function(){
      var newRow = $("<tr>");
              var cols = "";
              cols += '<td><input type="text" name="product"/></td>';
              cols += '<td><input type="text" name="price"/></td>';
              cols += '<td><input type="text" name="qty"/></td>';
              cols += '<td><input type="text" name="linetotal" readonly="readonly"/></td>';
              cols += '<td><a class="deleteRow"> x </a></td>';
              newRow.append(cols);
        $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
    });
    $("table.order-list").on("change", 'input[name^="price"], input[name^="qty"]', function (event) {
        calculateRow($(this).closest("tr"));
        calculateGrandTotal();
    });

    $("table.order-list").on("click", "a.deleteRow", function (event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        calculateGrandTotal();
    });


function calculateRow(row) {
    var price = +row.find('input[name^="price"]').val();
    var qty = +row.find('input[name^="qty"]').val();
    row.find('input[name^="linetotal"]').val((price * qty).toFixed(2));
}


function calculateGrandTotal(f) {
    var grandTotal = 0;
    $("table.order-list").find('input[name^="linetotal"]').each(function () {
        grandTotal += +$(this).val();
            });
    $("#grandtotal").text(grandTotal.toFixed(2));

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

from jsp i am getting the multiple values String array,

can any one tell me how can i retrive and set the values which i am sending from javascript.

i need to get values has to pass it to database.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  I have no idea what you are trying to do or what problem you are encountering.  Perhaps you need to focus your question more.  You are asking for help with javascript and putting data into your database, yet you showed us everything except for javascript and SQL.

Comment: Where is that javascript array in code, can you please tell me ?

Comment: @Brandon actually i am passing values from jsp through form, in java i m getting that value by request.getParameter, but i have one problem in that  here i am getting value as String array like this String[] productsBas = request.getParameterValues("product");
    String[] pricesBas= request.getParameterValues("price");
    String[] qtysBas= request.getParameterValues("qty"); 
   here i have to get details of each one and i need to insert into database, how can i iterate here. Thanks.

Comment: So you need to iterate over the array?  for (String qtyBas : qtysBas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] productsBas = request.getParameterValues("product");
String[] pricesBas= request.getParameterValues("price");
 String[] qtysBas= request.getParameterValues("qty"); 

for(int i=0;i<productsBas.length;i++){

 get values here using

  productsBas[i]  & pricesBas[i] and qtysBas[i] then save it
}
```

Comment: thanks but i have more then three String array in that three string values i have to pass in single query.

Comment: @Basha Ghouse those three having same no of values or different

Comment: @BashaGhouse i updated my answer.It should work for u.Because in your jsp you have same no of fields

Comment: this values are i m passing in form submit-ion in single click all are diff values  String[] productsBas = request.getParameterValues("product");
    String[] pricesBas= request.getParameterValues("price");
    String[] qtysBas= request.getParameterValues("qty");
    String[] linetotalsBas = request.getParameterValues("linetotal");

Comment: value are different but no of values are same try it it will definitely work for u